# How do I add Virtual Size or other columns in Process Hacker?

Tags: process-hacker

I'm running Process Hacker 2.39.124 on Windows 10 (x64, version 1607).

[This blog post](http://www.alex-ionescu.com/?p=246) has Process Hacker screenshots that include a Virtual Size column. I don't have that column when I run it.

I looked through the Options and Plugins dialogs and didn't see any way to add optional columns. How do I add columns like Virtual Size?

Comment: @fixer1234: Thanks for the tip - I added a proposed wiki excerpt for the tag.

Answer (score 0):

As sometimes happens, while writing this question I poked around some more and found the answer, so here it is for anyone who is as confused as I was.

The trick is to right-click any of the existing column headers such as Name. Then select Choose Columns... and the optional columns are all listed there.